# Capybara 2.0 ambiguous select

Tags: capybara

I have a dropdown that has the Value WEP and another value of WEP but have different Text WEP and WEP (Enterprise). How do I specify what one to select in capybara 2.0? Right now it is throwing an ambiguous error because both match.

Here is what I am doing now

```
 select @security_type[@index], from: 'wifis__encryption_type'
```

and @security_type[@index] = WEP

Comment: I've already answered a very similar question by you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15579109/841064

Comment: Yes but that was for a fill_in. im trying to use a select now

Comment: The idea is the same. Use `:exact` in Capybara 2.1 and `find(your_select).find(your_option).select_option` in Capybara 2.0